# How do I get rid of these weird video artifacts when using raspivid?

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, raspivid

I've got a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ powered via [NavoLabs POE Hat](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07CLCFLH8) with an [Arducam](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B012V1HEP4) for capturing video.  I'm using the following command to capture the video:

```
raspivid -t 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -o -
```

The video has some red and green horizontal wavy lines.  Here's an example recording:

- https://youtu.be/GKn2n8hxjHU
- https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sp_Q1rVNV_8iFqySbtpRA0CpMiUmIPkT (same video in original raspivid format)

What could be causing the red/green horizontal lines and how do I get rid of them?

Comment: try `-w 1920 -h 1080` - i.e. the apparent "native" resolution of that cameras video capability ... also `-o -` where are you sending this video stream?

Comment: Seems a bit better with 1920 and 1080.  Regarding `-o -`, I've tried piping it a few different places as well as redirecting to a file.  That doesn't seem to change the wavy lines.

Comment: do you get the same results when filming outside? I haven't used a webcam in years, but it looks like a typical result of a cheap webcam indoors, with low light levels - though another thing to try is a different framerate, say `-fps 30`